# Is /usr/bin/bash the same as /bin/bash (CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, bash, centos, hard-link

Are `/usr/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` the same thing? They seem to have the same inode number and attributes:

```
[vagrant@tmp-ansible-test-vm ip_lookup]$ ls -il /bin/bash /usr/bin/bash
1574356 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 960376 Nov 20  2015 /bin/bash
1574356 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 960376 Nov 20  2015 /usr/bin/bash
```

But `stat` only reports one link (not two as I would expect):

```
[vagrant@tmp-ansible-test-vm ip_lookup]$ stat /bin/bash
  File: ‘/bin/bash’
  Size: 960376      Blocks: 1880       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 1574356     Links: 1  # <--- Only one link????
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:shell_exec_t:s0
Access: 2018-01-29 19:48:46.749000000 +0000
Modify: 2015-11-20 05:02:31.000000000 +0000
Change: 2016-07-05 13:38:25.550000000 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Why would they have the same inode number, but only one link?

I'm using https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7 with Virtualbox for this VM if that makes a difference.
Is one location more "stable" than the other?

Output of `mount` (requested in comments):

```
(ip_lookup) [vagrant@tmp-ansible-test-vm ip_lookup]$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=239448k,nr_inodes=59862,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=50080k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Output of `ls -la /bin/bash /usr/bin/bash` (requested in comments):

```
(ip_lookup) [vagrant@tmp-ansible-test-vm ip_lookup]$ ls -la /bin/bash /usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 960376 Nov 20  2015 /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 960376 Nov 20  2015 /usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: Please add the `mount` output to the question.

Comment: What is the output of `mount`?  Could there be a bind mount at work here?

Comment: I am also pending to the idea of a symlink as @Mark suggests. Add the output of `ls -la /bin/bash /usr/bin/bash`

Comment: Ah, yes.  But @RuiFRibeiro, if it's `/bin` that's symlinked to `/usr/bin`, then the `ls` command you wrote won't show that.  `ls -ld /bin /usr/bin` should do it, though.

Comment: @Wildcard True indeed.

Comment: BINGO! `/bin` is symlinked to `/usr/bin`! Let me try to `readlink` them and see if that confirms it- it does. @Wildcard want to make an answer for me to accept?

Comment: @Ben, please accept the proposed duplicate—that's where I got the answer.

Comment: @Wildcard Good catch, it seems quite a puzzle work.